# Why does my camera choose an insane ISO & shutter time combo in Aperture mode?

Tags: camera-settings, sony-alpha, auto-iso

I noticed lately that my Sony A7S II will pick very high ISO (12800) combined with very short shutter times (1/8000s) when in aperture priority mode. What would cause it to do such a thing? Did I accidentally change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On some SONY Alpha cameras there is a setting for minimum shutter speed. It give you a option (when use AutoISO) to set more modest or more aggressive shutter speed. Please check, maybe you set somehow this option to very aggressive value.
You can found it at `MENU> Camera Settings>ISO AUTO Min. SS`.

The options are:

- FASTER (Faster)/FAST (Fast)
- STD (Standard)
- SLOW (Slow)/SLOWER (Slower)
- 1/4000―30"

You can find more information in the [manual](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1540/v1/en/contents/TP0000829903.html).